# RStudio plot() only shows black bars

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

When I call plot() in RStudio, I only receive black bars (see screenshot).

What could that be?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: clear your data and screen and then try plot() you will get error.

Comment: how to "clear data and screen"?

Comment: Click "Clear All" button in the Plot tab of R studio. Also clear you data if needed rm(list = ls())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your data and screen and then try plot() you will get error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think calling just plot() should produce an error

```
> plot()
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

So do you actually plot something?
Perhaps you should try to reset your par options.

```
.pardefault <- par(no.readonly = T)
```

or in R studio just remove all plots and try it again

Comment: > plot()
Error in nrow(p) : argument "p" is missing, with no default